# Moodle Mobile developing a plugin

Tags: plugins, moodle

I was working on Moodle mobile application and trying to develop a new plugin, so i tried to follow instructions in the following link: http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Moodle_Mobile_Developing_a_plugin_tutorial
I am stuck on this step: "Develop the Moodle local/mod/block/... plugin" in this link:
https://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MDL-30085 
at this line: **run "phpunit core_grade_external_testcase lib/grade/tests/externallib_test.php"**. My question is how to "run phpunit..."

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to install phpunit first

http://docs.moodle.org/dev/PHPUnit

Then you can run phpunit from the command line